# CGLib - control instance creation

Tags: java, cglib

I am using CGLib to enhance class A.

```
public class A { 
   public void printName(){
       System.out.println("guy");
   }
}
```

I have class B which extends class A.

```
public class B extends A{ 
  public void printName(){
      System.out.println("someone else!");
  }
}
```

How can I tell CGLib to instantiate B instead of A when I enhance it?

```
public A getEnhancedClass( boolean trueIfIWantBInsteadOfA ){
    e.setSuperclass( A.class ); // cannot change this
    e.setCallback( createDummyInterceptor() );// an interceptor that just invokesSuper
    /// ... missing code here
    return (A) e.create()
}
```

the following code should print "someone else!"

```
getEnhancedClass( true ).printName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cglib creates a subclass of the arument given in `Enhancer#setSuperclass`. If you subclass `A`, the proxy will not even know about the existance of `B`. Maybe you want to create a lazy proxy? Then you might want to look at the `LazyLoader` or `Dispatcher` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to intercept the constructor and return an instance of B and not invoke the A constructor.

Comment: How do you do that?